# Using another module in your module: imports vs. using loadChildren in routes

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-module

In my exploration of Angular, I've found two possible ways to use one module inside of another.

(Using the [angular-express-starter project](https://github.com/vladotesanovic/angular2-express-starter) for reference)

- **Method 1**:
  Declare it in the `imports` array. [For example](https://github.com/vladotesanovic/angular2-express-starter/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts#L24)

  ```
  @NgModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      SharedModule,
      FormsModule
    ]
  })
  ```
- **Method 2**:
  Use `loadChildren`in the routing. [For example](https://github.com/vladotesanovic/angular2-express-starter/blob/master/src/app/app.router.ts):

  ```
  export const routes: Route[] = [
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'weather'},
    { loadChildren: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule', path: 'dashboard' },
    { loadChildren: 'app/profile/profile.module#ProfileModule', path: 'profile' },
    { loadChildren: 'app/weather/weather.module#WeatherModule', path: 'weather' }
  ];
  ```

What are the practical differences between these two methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the practical differences between these two methods?

The biggest difference is that modules loaded via `loadChildren` will have their own injector whereas providers from imported modules are merged into one root injector. It means that you can't inject providers from the lazy loaded module into other lazy loaded modules.

Other differences:

- you can't use `loadChildren` if you don't use routing
- modules loaded via `loadChildren` will be loaded only when the corresponding route is navigated to

For more information read

- [Avoiding common confusions with modules in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f)

Answer (score 0):

When you're using `loadChildren`, it's called "Lazy Loading" and in total it helps us to decrease the startup time. Modules that are lazily loaded will only be loaded when the user navigates to their routes.

For more info about "Lazy Loading": https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html

Comment: We can also load module eagerly by using loadChildren